# Gmail verification

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-oauth

According to the new Gmail OAuth policies, certain authentication scopes require a new App Review process.

I want to replace the restricted scopes I'm currently using with just one non-restricted scope.

Does this mean I can simply skip the verification process? Or does this mean other granted scopes like the one from drive ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive') will be revoked or will my app will get an "unverified" screen?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914), you do not need to request for verification if your app is going to be used in any of the following scenarios:

- The app is not shared with anyone else.
- The app is used to send emails through Wordpress, or similar single
  account SMTP plug-ins.
- The owner and users of your apps belong to the same G Suite domain or
  customer.
- The app is trying to access data from users' Google Cloud Platform
  project. For instructions on using a service account, see [Using OAuth
  2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

As for your second question, if your app uses sensitive scopes or does not fall in the above scenarios, then yes, your apps will get the Unverified App screen.

> If you don't publish your app for review:
>
> - If your public application uses sensitive scopes that permit access to
>     certain user data, users of your application might see anUnverified
>     App screen.
> - To protect users and Google systems from abuse, applications that use
>     OAuth and Google Identity have certain quota restrictions based on the
>     risk level of the OAuth scopes an app uses. Failure to get your app
>     verified might result in your project quota getting exhausted. Learn
>     more about Unverified Apps.

You can visit the [FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914) if you have other questions.

Comment: If you want to use the GMail SMTP server with OAuth 2.0 authentication that requires the https://mail.google.com/ scope (as of Feb 2019).  That's the highest scope available.  I just went through a process that took 3+ months "proving" my app does what it should and was denied access to that scope.  It was all done through email with what seemed like canned messages from people on the other end expecting you were writing a phone/device app. In my case it was an IBM Mainframe system where the app was heavily used for business applications.  I am going to try again but I'm not holding my breath.

Answer (score 0):

If you request scopes that Google considers sensitive, you will most likely be denied approval. It is better to limit the scopes that you request to just the ones for identity.

If you don't your app will have this big warning that your app is not trusted while you wait for approval. Then your app will be denied.

Eliminate scopes until the request approval button is disabled. Once your scopes are limited to the point that Google does not require approval for your app you will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have added all the scopes used by your app on OAuth Consent  configuration screen in Google Cloud Console. Once you have done that, screen should flag you the scopes which need to go through verification.

Even if your app doesnt use any restricted scopes, it may be using some sensitive scopes for which you will have to go through OAuth verification process.

Hope this helps.